# Right align a menu list

Tags: html, css

```css
     body {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background-image: url("background.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
      }

      * {
        font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
      }

      .nav-bar {
        background-color: darkred;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 48px;
      }

      #navigation ul {
        list-style: none;
        float: right;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }

      #navigation ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
      }

      #navigation ul li:hover ul {
        display: block;
      }

      #navigation ul li {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
      }

      #navigation ul ul li {
        margin-left: -15px !important;
      }

      #navigation ul li ul li:first-child {
        margin-top: 15px;
      }

      #navigation ul ul li {
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        background-color: darkgreen;
      }

      #navigation ul li ul li:hover {
        background-color: blueviolet;
      }

      #navigation ul li:hover {
        background-color: firebrick;
      }

      #navigation ul li:last-child ul li { // Here is actually what the some magic has to be carried out actually.  
        right: 100px;
        background: black;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Right hand sided navigation menu with level 1 drop down -->
    <title>HTML - CSS Lessons</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <nav id="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item 6</a> // This is the place where the menu has to come out of screen
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 6 Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 6 Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 6 Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why the last I mean the menu in black background appears inside the screen? How to pull it out? I have used "#navigation ul li:last-child ul li"  to make the last drop down as black color. But, don't have any idea of pulling it out from the screen's right hand side. Can't we make use of "#navigation ul li:last-child ul li" to pull out the menu out of the screen?

Comment: What do you mean menu has to come out of screen, Could you explain with image or something?

Comment: https://prntscr.com/10f5ixk Check this. The drop down menu looks weird..

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

* {
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav-bar {
  background-color: darkred;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
}

#navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#navigation ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}

#navigation ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

#navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

#navigation ul ul li {
  margin-left: -15px !important;
}

#navigation ul li ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#navigation ul ul li {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

#navigation ul li ul li:hover {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#navigation ul li:hover {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

#navigation ul li:last-child ul li {
  position: relative;
  right: 21%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Right hand sided navigation menu with level 1 drop down -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>HTML - CSS Lessons</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <nav id="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item 6</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 6 Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 6 Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Submenu 6 Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Got an answer to this query... put right: -65px;